# Sporadic error downloading data from PHP application

Tags: php, internet-explorer

A PHP application is offering binary data as a download:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");       
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: private");   
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("expires: 0");      
set_time_limit(0);
ob_clean();
flush();    
@readfile($completefilename); exit;
```

$completefilename is a stream like "ftp://user:pwd@..."

The size of the data can be several MByte. It works fine, but sporadically I get the following error:

[image: Error]

Comment: I hope you are using IE only for testing but not as your main browser.

Comment: @ThiefMaster what exactly is wrong with IE as the main browser?

Comment: @Pekka: Are you kidding?

Comment: @Tomalak  Of course there are better browsers around. But using IE is not a practice that needs to be called out in an off-topic comment, like when the OP has a SQL injection vulnerability in their code. The "IE sucks" meme is important but there should be a limit. In version 8, it's a fine browser for everyday use.

Comment: No. Maybe IE9 is - but 8 is not really. Just look at this meaningless error in the question.

Comment: To go back on topic: you should consider using X-Sendfile so PHP just tells the webserver to send a file instead of actually reading/sending the file via PHP.

Comment: @Thief I don't think Firefox's and Chrome's error messages are much better if a file download times out after the headers have been output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely that the remote stream is occasionally down, or times out.

Also as @fab says it could be that the file you are trying to load is larger than your script's memory.

You should start logging the errors `readfile()` returns, e.g. using the [`error_log` php.ini directive](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/log-php-errors-log-errors-error-log/).

If this needs to be completely foolproof, I think you'll have to use something more refined than `readfile()` that allows to set a timeout (like `curl`, or `readfile` with [stream context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)).

You could then catch any errors that occur while downloading, and serve a locally hosted fallback document instead. That document could e.g. be a text file containing the message "Resource xyz could not be loaded".

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything in your error logs?
Maybe PHP is running out of memory because readfile() needs to pull the while file into memory. Make sure memory_limit is larger than the largest file  you work on with readfile(). Another option is to output the file in chunks using fread().